# execute read command from var

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to add "debug" optio to my script, for that I added a read commands in specific places in the code. Basically it look like this:

```
#define it
READ_USER_INPUT_IF_IN_DEBUG_MODE="read -p 'press any key to continue:'"

#calling it
${READ_USER_INPUT_IF_IN_DEBUG_MODE}
```

the screen output is not as desired;

```
sm2edolt01.corp.nyx.com:/home/oracle/nir >./a.sh
'press
```

Tried to replace the `'` with `\"` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting won't work, use any array:

```
#define it                                                                                                          
READ_USER_INPUT_IF_IN_DEBUG_MODE=(read -p 'press any key to continue:')                                             

#calling it                                                                                                         
"${READ_USER_INPUT_IF_IN_DEBUG_MODE[@]}"
```

See [this page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays#usage) for more details on Bash arrays handling.

Comment: One thing though. I need that the command `"${READ_USER_INPUT_IF_IN_DEBUG_MODE[@]}"` will not return error in case of empty variable. Setting it to empty string resulting in `command not found`

Comment: Yes, that doens't work. Use `READ_USER_INPUT_IF_IN_DEBUG_MODE=()` instaed of the empty string